# Where are remains of laika?

Tags: history, russia, animals, sputnik

I have already tried searching about laika
But one thing i am not able to find

What about remains of famous space dog laika? where are her remains? In space or fell back to earth?

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Laika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laika#Voyage) says: "Over five months later, after 2,570 orbits, Sputnik 2—including Laika's remains—disintegrated during re-entry on 14 April 1958."

Comment: Excessively cremated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Uhoh answered in comments: *

> The Wikipedia article about Laika says: "Over five months later, after 2,570 orbits, Sputnik 2—including Laika's remains—disintegrated during re-entry on 14 April 1958."

For basic historical questions like this, it's always worth looking at Wikipedia first, and then coming here if you cannot find the info you need.